# Update step in PyTorch implementation of Newton's method

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pytorch, newtons-method, automatic-differentiation

I'm trying to get some insight into how PyTorch works by implementing Newton's method for solving *x = cos(x)*. Here's a version that works:

```
x =  Variable(DoubleTensor([1]), requires_grad=True)

for i in range(5):
    y = x - torch.cos(x)
    y.backward()
    x = Variable(x.data - y.data/x.grad.data, requires_grad=True)

print(x.data) # tensor([0.7390851332151607], dtype=torch.float64) (correct)
```

This code seems inelegant (inefficient?) to me since it's recreating the entire computational graph during each step of the `for` loop (right?). I tried to avoid this by simply updating the data held by each of the variables instead of recreating them:

```
x =  Variable(DoubleTensor([1]), requires_grad=True)
y = x - torch.cos(x)
y.backward(retain_graph=True)

for i in range(5):
    x.data = x.data - y.data/x.grad.data
    y.data = x.data - torch.cos(x.data)
    y.backward(retain_graph=True)

print(x.data) # tensor([0.7417889255761136], dtype=torch.float64) (wrong)
```

Seems like, with `DoubleTensor`s, I'm carrying enough digits of precision to rule out round-off error. So where's the error coming from?

Possibly related: The above snippet breaks without the `retain_graph=True` flag set at every step if the `for` loop. The error message I get if I omit it within the loop --- but retain it on line 3 --- is:
*RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the **first time**.* This seems like evidence that I'm misunderstanding something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your first version of code is optimal, meaning that it is not creating a computation graph on every run.

```
# initial guess
guess = torch.tensor([1], dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad = True) 

# function to optimize
def my_func(x): 
    return x - torch.cos(x)

def newton(func, guess, runs=5): 
    for _ in range(runs): 
        # evaluate our function with current value of `guess`
        value = my_func(guess)
        value.backward()
        # update our `guess` based on the gradient
        guess.data -= (value / guess.grad).data
        # zero out current gradient to hold new gradients in next iteration 
        guess.grad.data.zero_() 
    return guess.data # return our final `guess` after 5 updates

# call starts
result = newton(my_func, guess)

# output of `result`
tensor([0.7391], dtype=torch.float64)
```

In each run, our function `my_func()`, which defines the computation graph, is evaluated with the current `guess` value. Once that returns the result, we compute the gradient (with `value.backward()` call). With this gradient, we now update our `guess` and zero-out our gradients so that it will be afresh for holding the gradients the next time we call `value.backward()` (i.e. it stops accumulating the gradient; without zeroing out the gradient, it would by default starts accumulating the gradients. But, we want to avoid that behaviour here).